# how to close a modal dialog in showEvent?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I can't believe I have to ask this, but I can't get a PyQt5 modal dialog box to close from the `showEvent`.

Here is a miniature example program demonstrating the problem.  The intended behavior of this test program is since `somethingWentTerriblyWrong` is set, as soon as `btnShowDialog` is pressed, the modal dialog should perhaps appear for an instant, if even that long, and then close automatically, but as you can see from the screenshot below this does not happen.

```
# test.py

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QWidget, QLabel, QGridLayout, QPushButton
from PyQt5.Qt import Qt

def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    mainForm = MainForm()
    mainForm.show()
    app.exec()
# end main

class MainForm(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUi()

        self.myDialog = MyDialog(self)
        # set that something went wrong in the dialog so it should close immediately in the showEvent
        self.myDialog.somethingWentTerriblyWrong = True
    # end function

    def initUi(self):
        # set default form size and location
        self.setGeometry(400, 400, 400, 275)

        # declare a button
        self.btnShowDialog = QPushButton('show dialog')
        self.btnShowDialog.clicked.connect(self.btnShowDialogClicked)

        # increase the font size
        setFontSize(self.btnShowDialog, 16)

        # declare a layout and add the label to the layout
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.btnShowDialog)

        # add the layout to the form
        self.setLayout(self.gridLayout)
    # end function

    def btnShowDialogClicked(self):
        retVal = self.myDialog.exec()
        print('retVal = ' + str(retVal))
    # end function

# end class

class MyDialog(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.initUi()

        self.somethingWentTerriblyWrong = False
    # end function

    def initUi(self):
        self.setGeometry(250, 250, 250, 175)

        self.lblDialog = QLabel('label on Dialog')

        # center the label and increase the font size
        self.lblDialog.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        setFontSize(self.lblDialog, 15)

        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lblDialog)

        self.setLayout(self.gridLayout)
    # end function

    def showEvent(self, event):
        super(MyDialog, self).showEvent(event)

        # if something went terribly wrong, close this dialog form
        if self.somethingWentTerriblyWrong:
            print('in if self.somethingWentTerriblyWrong:')
            # self.reject()
            self.close()
        # end if

    # end function

# end class

def setFontSize(widget, fontSize):
    font = widget.font()
    font.setPointSize(fontSize)
    widget.setFont(font)
# end function

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In `MyDialog`, I would have expected either the self.reject() or self.close() lines to get the dialog to close, however on Ubuntu 18.04 at least the modal dialog turns dark and hangs:

[image]

I'm certain execution is getting in the `if` statement in `MyDialog`'s show event because the terminal output is:

```
$ python3 test.py 
in if self.somethingWentTerriblyWrong:
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are prematurely closing the widget, in the `showEvent()` method the widget is visible but the painting on the device has not yet been done so when calling the `close()` method you stop the painting, and it is not hidden because the internal flag was not updated generating *undefined behavior*.

The solution is to invoke the `close()`method ( or `reject()` method) an instant after `showEvent()` after an instant (leaving the time for the internal flags to update correctly) using `QTimer` or `QMetaObject`:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer, QMetaObject

# ...


class MyDialog(QDialog):
    # ...
    def showEvent(self, event):
        super(MyDialog, self).showEvent(event)

        # if something went terribly wrong, close this dialog form
        if self.somethingWentTerriblyWrong:
            print("in if self.somethingWentTerriblyWrong:")
            QTimer.singleShot(0, self.close)
            # or
            # - QMetaObject.invokeMethod(self, "close", Qt.QueuedConnection)
            # - QTimer.singleShot(0, self.reject)
            # - QMetaObject.invokeMethod(self, "reject", Qt.QueuedConnection)
```

Answer (score 0):

Complete working example based on eyllanesc's answer:

```
# CloseDialogInShowEvent.py

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QWidget, QLabel, QGridLayout, QPushButton
from PyQt5.Qt import Qt
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer

def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    mainForm = MainForm()
    mainForm.show()
    app.exec()
# end main

class MainForm(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUi()

        self.myDialog = MyDialog(self)
        # set that something went wrong in the dialog so it should close immediately in the showEvent
        self.myDialog.somethingWentTerriblyWrong = True
    # end function

    def initUi(self):
        # set default form size and location
        self.setGeometry(400, 400, 400, 275)

        # declare a button
        self.btnShowDialog = QPushButton('show dialog')
        self.btnShowDialog.clicked.connect(self.btnShowDialogClicked)

        # increase the font size
        setFontSize(self.btnShowDialog, 16)

        # declare a layout and add the label to the layout
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.btnShowDialog)

        # add the layout to the form
        self.setLayout(self.gridLayout)
    # end function

    def btnShowDialogClicked(self):
        retVal = self.myDialog.exec()
        print('retVal = ' + str(retVal))
    # end function

# end class

class MyDialog(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.initUi()

        self.somethingWentTerriblyWrong = False

        self.tmrClose = QTimer(self)
        self.tmrClose.setInterval(200)
        self.tmrClose.timeout.connect(self.tmrCloseTimeout)
    # end function

    def initUi(self):
        self.setGeometry(250, 250, 250, 175)

        self.lblDialog = QLabel('label on Dialog')

        # center the label and increase the font size
        self.lblDialog.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        setFontSize(self.lblDialog, 15)

        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lblDialog)

        self.setLayout(self.gridLayout)
    # end function

    def showEvent(self, event):
        super(MyDialog, self).showEvent(event)

        # if something went terribly wrong, close this dialog form
        if self.somethingWentTerriblyWrong:
            print('in if self.somethingWentTerriblyWrong:')
            self.tmrClose.start()
        # end if
    # end function

    def tmrCloseTimeout(self):
        self.reject()
    # end function

# end class

def setFontSize(widget, fontSize):
    font = widget.font()
    font.setPointSize(fontSize)
    widget.setFont(font)
# end function

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```